# I am not able to download text file in django

Tags: django, download

```
log_path = settings.BASE_DIR + '/uploaded_files/logs/'
# log_file =  user + '_' +datetime.datetime.now().__str__()
log_file = str(random.randint(1, 100)) + '_' + datetime.datetime.now().__str__()
log_file = log_path + '%s.txt' % log_file
```

download_error(log_file)

```
def download_error(log_file):
file_path = log_file
file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    print "DOWNLOAD ERROR FILE"
    with open(file_path,'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type = "text/plain")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = %s' % file_name   
    return response
raise Http404
```

I am not getting the file downloaded???

Comment: IMHO, it would be easier to read if you did: `log_filename = "%d_%s.txt" % (random.randint(1,100), datetime.datetime.now()` followed by `log_file = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "uploaded_files/logs", log_filename)`

Comment: Regarding your problem, what is the problem? Are you recieving a 404? The `DOWNLOAD ERROR FILE` is being printed? What is the content of `log_file` on the `download_error` function?

Comment: It prints "DOWNLOAD ERROR FILE" on terminal but the file which needs to get downloaded do not get downloaded... and if i print response it gets the filename and log_file is also generated.. moreover i dont get 404

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have correctly opened the file, but failed to do anything with it.

Also, you are not quoting the filename.

To correct that, maybe the following will work:

```
with open(file_path,'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type = "text/plain")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file_name
```

---

Rather than using `HttpResponse`, look into [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects), which should be more tailored to you use case.

Comment: I tried that as well but still file not download as attachment. It prints the content of file on terminal by fh.read()

Comment: Now I printed "response" as well and i get: 

Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = 73_2017-08-17 10:47:28.370844.txt

Headers not matching Please correct the file

Comment: The `read`, by itself, does not print on terminal. Maybe some logging confusion?

Comment: @MirUmer Updated the answer

Comment: Not exactly. I meant that not using `"%s"` was a problem. I am not sure if that would solve everything.

Comment: Now I shifted the code to Views directly and i get file downloaded but its not getting the file which is already stored in "uploaded_files/logs" folder..

It creates a new file with empty data and downloaded that only.


Now my code is: 

response = HttpResponse(content_type = "text/plain")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "%s"' % os.path.basename(log_file)
                print "Response:-", response
                return response

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I used, and it worked for sending txt file by django response:

```
import csv

    def download_error(log_file):
    file_path = log_file
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        print "DOWNLOAD ERROR FILE"
        with open(file_path,'r') as f:
            #Added code comes here
            #Read content of txt file, create a response, pass it to a 
            #csv_writer, write contents using the csv_writer, return 
            #response   
            contents = f.read()
            response = HttpResponse(content_type = "text/csv")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename = %s' % file_name  
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow(contents)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

In this way, when the endpoint is called, it will download the txt file directly.
Note that, in the content_type, i put "text/csv" and not "text/plain", not sure why but this is the one that worked.